# Ajax post to .net mvc controller timing out

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The code sample below does run as intended, but for my own edification I would like to understand why I need to stringify the position object. If I do not stringify the object the controller eventually times out.

```
function onClick(e) {
            var g = new geoLoc2('geolocation', function (position) {
                position.regId= window.localStorage.getItem("registrationId");
                position.regType= "self";
                position.playerId="1234567890";
                console.log("this is position:" + JSON.stringify(position));

                var stringy = JSON.stringify(position);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://192.168.1.142/webapitest2/CheckIn",
                    data: stringy,
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.localStorage.setItem("actionToken", data.ActionToken);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(error.responseText);
                        console.log(jsonValue);
                        //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
                    }
                });
            }).checkGPS();

        }
```

Here is the controller:

```
// POST: CheckIn
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(CheckInViewModel json)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { error = 'Invalid Model' });
        }

        return Json(new { Success= 'True' });
    }
```

I have also played around with trying to post just as a string and then convert it into an object at the controller with the same timeout result.

There is a similar question here: [Ajax POST call to ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016331/ajax-post-call-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-giving-neterr-connection-reset)