# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult not returning responseText in jQuery.post fail callback function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery `$.post` to post some data to an ActionResult method inside my controller. When an error is thrown in the controller, it should return the error message within the responseText of the response but it's not working.

The post request is hitting the controller.

The callback function `fail` seems to be triggered. Just not getting the error message returned. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

This is jQuery posting data:

```
var postData = ["1","2","3"];

$.post('/MyController/GetSomething', $.param(postData, true))
      .done(function (data) {
              alert('Done!');                        
      })
      .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(xhr.responseText); //xhr.responseText is empty   
      });
 });
```

Controllers

```
    public class MyController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult GetSomething(List ids)
        {
            try
            {
                GetSomeData(ids);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ThrowJsonError(new Exception(String.Format("The following error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString())));
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult ThrowJsonError(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;

            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Update**
What's interesting is that if I move some of the logic from out of the BaseController and into the MyController, I am able to get the desired result.

Why would this happen?

```
public class MyController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult GetSomething(List<string> ids)
        {
            try
            {
                GetSomeData(ids);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;

                return Json(new { Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it reach to the controller or gives an error before?

Comment: Yes, it does reach the controller. If an exception is then thrown in the Controller then the `Message` doesn't come back as `xhr.ResponseText = ""`

Comment: if you put alert(data.Message);  before alert('Done!');  what happend?

Comment: I've some question here, what is in `GetSomeData(ids);` after this you redirect to index action, what is in `Index`  and you had not passed any data from `GetSomething` to `index`

Comment: @DanielVorph When the exception is thrown in the Controller, I am definitely hitting the `.fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(xhr.responseText); //xhr.responseText is empty   
      });` function.

Comment: @Div It's not what's in `GetSomeData` that the issue, I know this because If I replace `GetSomeData(ids);` with `throw new NullReferenceException();` then an exception is forced, it will then step into the `catch` block and `return ThrowJsonError` and then never hit `RedirectToAction("Index")`. Still `xhr.ResponseText = ""`

Comment: @jgill09 Can you post your `Index` action

Comment: @Div The `Index` action is currently empty.

Comment: @Div `return View()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because you have an invalid `StatusDescription` being set in the `ThrowJsonError` function.  It has line feed characters which cause unexpected results in an Http Header.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917212/why-does-adding-a-newline-to-statusdescription-in-asp-net-close-the-connection)

The issue is being obfuscated because your first example has you set the `StatusDescription` to the `Message` property of a new `Exception` you are constructing which will contain line feeds and stack trace info because you call `ex.ToString()`.  The second one works because you are just setting the `StatusDescription` to `ex.Message` and that doesn't contain problematic characters

To be safe, you probably should just use a relatively benign `StatusDescription` since you don't really need it for anything anyway (you can get the `Message` in the `fail()` either way.

Note the following code works (still do not recommend it):

```
public ActionResult ThrowJsonError(Exception ex)
{
   Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
   Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message; // does not work
   Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' '); // works

   return Json(new { Message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Ah understood. Thank you for helping and taking the time to explain.